# Sort a dataframe which only has one column but keep the same format

Tags: r

Have a dataframe with column, I just want to sort the numbers descending, and keep the format of file a dataframe with same column name and row names.

```
df <- structure(list(PC1 = c(0.799780548221684, 0.795730424977294, 
0.832486223147844, 0.781317878179846, 0.731616836371459, 0.806050349534197, 
0.843632585345136, 0.789598905674104, 0.817326659093254, -0.809254508281934, 
0.830418198715417, 0.835210246262256, 0.805101272196506, 0.82710709201306, 
0.829909348164638, 0.837074218693618, -0.78322895041798)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Q6Br1", 
"Q6Br2", "Q6Br3", "Q6Br4", "Q6Br5", "Q6Br6", "Q6Br7", "Q6Br8", 
"Q6Br9", "Q6Br10", "Q6Br11", "Q6Br12", "Q6Br13", "Q6Br14", "Q6Br15", 
"Q6Br16", "Q6Br17"))
```

When i try to sort it, it becomes a list. If i try to sort as dataframe, it loses the column name.

Comment: `df[order(-df$PC1), , drop = FALSE]`  or using `dplyr` : `df %>% arrange(desc(PC1))`

Comment: is it possible to do that without specifying the variable name PC1, can it be ordered by column position 1 (the variable name may change so rather the code orders by the column rather than the variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the column number to arrange the data, here are couple of options.

Using `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% arrange(-pick(1L))
# Or
# df %>% arrange(desc(pick(1L)))

#              PC1
#Q6Br7   0.8436326
#Q6Br16  0.8370742
#Q6Br12  0.8352102
#Q6Br3   0.8324862
#Q6Br11  0.8304182
#Q6Br15  0.8299093
#Q6Br14  0.8271071
#Q6Br9   0.8173267
#Q6Br6   0.8060503
#Q6Br13  0.8051013
#Q6Br1   0.7997805
#Q6Br2   0.7957304
#Q6Br8   0.7895989
#Q6Br4   0.7813179
#Q6Br5   0.7316168
#Q6Br17 -0.7832290
#Q6Br10 -0.8092545
```

In base R :

```
df[order(-df[[1]]), , drop = FALSE]
```

Comment: Brilliant many thanks. Just one extra, if you don't mind me asking, is it possible to order by descending absolute value, but keep the positive/negative sign in the data?

Comment: Yes, you may use `df %>% arrange(desc(abs(pick(1L))))` @Shaun